# How to resume Vagrant shell provisioner from the error point?

Tags: vagrant, kong

In the provisioner shell file, it will spend much time installing many packages. Unfortunately, it can't execute successfully at one time due to some issues(network, unknown), so it has to been tried to execute several times. But it always starts to execute from the beginning. It will spend much time and if one issue occurred, it has to been executed again. Then it becomes difficult to install all packages at one time.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to resume the provisoner and don't need to install packages that have been installed previously. For example, the Vagrantfile from https://github.com/Kong/kong-vagrant whose [provision.sh](https://github.com/Kong/kong-vagrant/blob/master/provision.sh) will install many packages one by one.

Comment: you can't .. shell scripts are limited by nature and for provisioning that's the reason tools like chef, puppet, ansible are replacing shell (among other advantages)

Comment: if you want to use shell instead of other configuration tools , better solution would be to run command in while loop until it downloads everything ( even if network issue, it will resume automatically )